# python unquote. Как декодировать строку полностью?

Tags: python-3.x

Почему unquote не декодирует строку полностью ?

```
import urllib.parse
result_files = "%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b"
p = urllib.parse.unquote(result_files,'utf-8')
print(p)
```

результат: оченьдлинноеназв�%b

Comment: Ну так у вас исходная строка обрезана. В конце явно остановилось на полуслове *(точнее, на полубукве)* `%d0%b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

код для поиска проблемы:

```
for i in range(3, len(result_files) + 1, 3):
    text = result_files[:i]
    p = urllib.parse.unquote(text, 'utf-8')
    print(text)
    print(p)
    print()
```

смотрите, каждому символу отводится 2 символа вида `%xx`, в результате если вы посмотрите на строку, то увидите, что она не кратна 6 и заканчивается на

```
%d0%b
```

т.е. тут явный обрыв строки

должно заканчиваться на

```
%d0%b0
```

это буква `'a'`

поэтому вы и видите в конце спецсимвол `�%b`

Но в любом случае, даже если исправить концовку, у вас записано лишь `оченьдлинноеназва`

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно строка обрезается.